# How to iterate all possible equations given certain conditions? Nedle game solver

Tags: python, math, iteration, equation

[image: A nerdle game solution for 2023-01-06]

I'm trying to write a code in python that solves the nerdle game problems (https://nerdlegame.com/). Right now, I have the following:

```
allNumbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
searchedEq = "00000000"


allOperations = "+-/*" # the four basic arithmetical operations
operationsNotInEq = "+-"
operationsInEq = set(allOperations) - set(operationsNotInEq)

print(operationsInEq)

numbersinEq = ""

numbersNotInEq = "843"

numbersInEq = list(allNumbers - {eval(i) for i in list(numbersNotInEq)})
```

The string values from above are according to the first equation in the attached picture. The numbers 8, 4 and 3 are not in the final equation. Therefore, I don't want any iterated equations that contain numbers in numbersNotInE. The same can be said about the arithmetic operations. Addition and subtraction (from the first row in picture) are not in the final equation. Hence, the iterated equations cannot contain addition and subtraction.

I have two problems right now:

1. What is the easiest/best way to iterate all possible equations given the conditions?
   I know there a lot of possible answers, but not infinitely many since there is a limit to the length of the equation and only certain possible numbers/arithmetic operations in the equation.

I would greatly appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

There are 17,723 possible equations for the Classic Nerdle. This is stated in the FAQ of the game and they can be viewed [here](https://github.com/PedroKKr/Nerdle-Equations/blob/main/NerdleClassicRestricted.txt).

With all the equations, you can filter the list to the ones that match the patterns already seen. To do this, you could create a function that takes as argument the pattern seen and filters the list. Supposing the pattern is a sequence of 0s, 1s and 2s (black, purple, green), then the function could be:

```
def pattern_filter(pattern,inserted_equation,possible_equations):
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(pattern,inserted_equation)):
    if x == 0:
        possible_equations = [eq for eq in possible_equations if y not in eq]
    elif x == 1:
        possible_equations = [eq for eq in possible_equations if y in eq and eq[i] != y]
    else:
        possible_equations = [eq for eq in possible_equations if eq[i] == y]
```